# How to create rotating groups that don't overlap.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do you split 28 people into groups of 7, for 6 rotations, without overlapping the same people into the same groups repetitively?

Comment: First, what do you mean by "rotations"? That is a word of many possible meanings, and we cannot intuit exactly what you are after. Second, what have you understood about the problem, and what have you tried? Where did you run into trouble On this site we prefer to help people learn mathematics themselves, not do their homework problems for them so they don't have to learn it. Telling us what you've tried shows us that you have tried, and allows us to assist you where you actually need help.

Comment: Hi Paul, this is not a homework problem, it is actually a real life problem. I am simply trying to take a group of 28 people & split them into 4 groups of 7 each. I am trying to do that 6 times & to create new groups each time that don't have the same members in them. I want my team to work together to perform team building games, but I want them all to get a chance to work with different team members. Presently I have given up on finding a mathematical approach and I have just sorted them into groups the best I can. If it is too much to ask, I will just sort it out.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but if I were trying to do this, "experiment design" are the words I'd include in my search.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to come up with a means of picking groupings that followed some simple algorithm, but in the end they either failed miserably to produce useful results, or devolved in the later groupings to brute force.

So instead I'll discuss what is possible and what is not. The first problem is how to interpret "new groups each time that don't have the same members in them". If that just means no two groups have the exact same roster, then the problem is trivial. Just pick one person from each group, and each "day" (for convenience, I'll pretend you are regrouping daily) rotate those four through the groups. On day five, you'd have to pick a different person from each group and rotate them instead. That would give you 24 distinct groups, but in each group there will be five people who are always together, and a sixth who is with them 2/3 of the time.

---

Presumably that is not going to be suitable, but what else you can do is really going to depend on what exactly you want to accomplish here. Clearly you must have some people grouped together more than once - to form a group on the second day, you need to pull 7 people from only 4 groups of the first day, so at least one of the groups must supply more than one person. Suppose your goal is to make sure every pair of people are together at least once, and to minimize the number of times any two people share a group. You might try to follow these rules in picking your groups:

- Every pair of two people must be in the same group at least once.
- No two groups should have more than two people in common.
- No pair of people should be together more than twice.

Unfortunately, these rules are incompatible. There are $\binom{28}2 = 378$ distinct ways of pairing your $28$ people. In each group of $7$, there are $\binom 72 = 21$ pairings. On the second day, the only two people in common rule means that new groups can only take one pair from any of the first-day groups, so they must take two people from three of the groups, and the seventh person from the fourth group. This means in each group there will be exactly three pairings that duplicate pairings on the first day. Thus the first day introduces $4 \times 21 = 84$ pairings of the $378$ pairings needed. But because of the duplicates, each group on the second day introduces only $18$ new pairings, increasing the total to $84 +4*18 = 156$ pairings.

On the third day, the groups could be compared against either the first or second days' groups, with three pairings in each group duplicating pairings of the other day. Because of the "no pairings occur more than twice" rule, these two sets of duplicate pairings cannot overlap, for $6$ duplications of earlier pairings. Thus each third-day group will introduce only $15$ new pairings, bringing the total up to $216$. Similarly,

- groups on the fourth day will introduce only $12$ new pairings, raising the total to $264$.
- groups on the fifth day will introduce only $9$ new pairings, raising the total to $300$ pairings.
- groups on the six day will introduce only $6$ new pairings, raising the total to $324$ pairings.

Thus the second and third rules only allow $324$ of the $378$ pairings required by the first rule.

---

If you want everyone to interact with everyone else, we can drop the third rule and allow some limited violation of the second rule. To see how, let me solve the simpler problem of having only $16$ people first, with only four people in each group. In this case you can get all $\binom{16}2 = 120$ possible pairings in only $5$ days. I will identify the people with a letter from $A$ to $D$ and a digit from $1$ to $4$.

- Day 1: $\{A1, A2, A3, A4\}, \{B1, B2, B3, B4\}, \{C1, C2, C3, C4\}, \{D1, D2, D3, D4\}$
- Day 2: $\{A1, B1, C1, D1\}, \{A2, B2, C2, D2\}, \{A3, B3, C3, D3\}, \{A4, B4, C4, D4\}$
- Day 3: $\{A1, B2, C3, D4\}, \{A2, B3, C4, D1\}, \{A3, B4, C1, D2\}, \{A4, B1, C2, D3\}$
- Day 4: $\{A1, B3, C4, D2\}, \{A2, B4, C1, D3\}, \{A3, B1, C2, D4\}, \{A4, B2, C3, D1\}$
- Day 5: $\{A1, B4, C2, D3\}, \{A2, B1, C3, D4\}, \{A3, B2, C4, D1\}, \{A4, B3, C1, D2\}$

We can try to convert this to solution for $28$ people by leaving $A1, B1, C1, D1$ as representing single people, but switching the other designations to representing a couple: $24$ of the $28$ people will be paired into couples that will always be together, each represented by names ending in $2, 3, 4$, while the names ending in $1$ will represent the four "loners".

This *almost* works. It satisfies the condition that for any two people, they will be together in at least one group. It also satisfies the condition that any two groups have at most two people in common. The problem is, while on days 1,3,4,5 all groups have seven members, on day 2, $\{A1, B1, C1, D1\}$ has only four members while the other three have eight members each.

To solve this, duplicate the day 2 groups on day 6. Also, split the $A$ couples in two: $A2.1, A2.2, A3.1, A3.2, A4.1, A4.2$. On day 2, move the $.1$ members to the first group, and on day 6, move the $.2$ members to the first group:

- Day 2: $\{A1, B1, C1, D1, A2.1, A3.1, A4.1\}, \{A2.2, B2, C2, D2\}, \{A3.2, B3, C3, D3\}, \{A4.2, B4, C4, D4\}$
- Day 6: $\{A1, B1, C1, D1, A2.2, A3.2, A4.2\}, \{A2.1, B2, C2, D2\}, \{A3.1, B3, C3, D3\}, \{A4.1, B4, C4, D4\}$

Then there will be seven members in each group on these days as well. And the duplication on day 6 with the swapping of roles ensures both members of the split couples are still grouped with the people they would have been had the $4,8,8,8$ groupings been allowed. On days 2 and 6, the first group has four members in common with the $\{A1, A2, A3, A4\}$ group from day 1, in violation of the second rule. And day 2 and day 6 groups may have six members in common. But all other pairs of groups still have at most two members in common.